# DevExpress XtraGrid ExportToXlsx showing checked/unchecked for RepositoryItemCheckEdit instead of checkbox images

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, devexpress, xtragrid

We're using an devexpress XtraGrid to show and export various data to Excel.

After an upgrade to DevExpress 11.1 there was a functionality change to improve Excel export. 
[Excel export change](http://devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2011v1/index.xml?page=31)

However this changed the export from showing little checkbox images in excel to showing text labels checked/unchecked.

Is there a way to get the old functionality back to show little checkbox images (we have the same issues with RepositoryItemImageComboBox )

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set `ExportMode = ExportMode.Value` on the `RepositoryItemCheckEdit`.